# Docking station for Thinkpad T14 Gen2 and legacy devices

Tags: laptop

Can someone recommend a docking station for a Lenovo Thinkpad T14, Gen2?  I need to connect an HDMI external monitor, a legacy Kensington Trackball with a USB-A connector, a legacy keyboard (actually PS/2 but with a USB-A adapter), a USB stick, and the power supply. A 3.5mm audio jack would be good but not vital. I'm having trouble finding one with enough USB-A ports.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! I believe any Thunderbolt 4 or even USB-C dock should work? [Tons of generic options out there](https://www.amazon.com/Oditton-Adapter-USB-C-Transfer-Laptops/dp/B0CHJV9L6N/), some are nicer and have additional ports/Thunderbolt support but more expensive.